# DFT matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, dft

What's the easiest way to get the [DFT matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) for 2-d DFT in python? I could not find such function in [numpy.fft](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html). Thanks!

Comment: See also [scipy.linalg.dft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.dft.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think this is built in.  However, direct calculation is straightforward:

```
import numpy as np
def DFT_matrix(N):
    i, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))
    omega = np.exp( - 2 * pi * 1J / N )
    W = np.power( omega, i * j ) / sqrt(N)
    return W
```

*EDIT* For a 2D FFT matrix, you can use the following:

```
x = np.zeros(N, N) # x is any input data with those dimensions
W = DFT_matrix(N)
dft_of_x = W.dot(x).dot(W)
```

Comment: @AlexI although it may have a similar effect, technically you should apply it: `dft_of_x = W.dot(x).dot(W.T)`.
You cannot get away with `dft_of_x = (W.dot(W)).dot(x)`. Applying only a matrix from the left can only transform the columns of `x`; this will be a (not DFT) 1D transform.

Comment: @ThomasArildsen Thanks for the technical heads-up!! But I'm still curious, why "although it may have a similar effect"?? Isn't that just wrong?

Comment: Just one remark.. when I compare your DFT_matrix with the one from np.fft.fft(np.eye(N)), I see a factor of np.pi "missing". I know it is just a scaling factor, but wanted to mention it

Answer (score 22):

The easiest and most likely the fastest method would be using fft from SciPy.

```
import scipy as sp

def dftmtx(N):
    return sp.fft(sp.eye(N))
```

If you know even faster way (might be more complicated) I'd appreciate your input.

Just to make it more relevant to the main question - you can also do it with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

dftmtx = np.fft.fft(np.eye(N))
```

When I had benchmarked both of them I have an impression scipy one was marginally faster but I 
have not done it thoroughly and it was sometime ago so don't take my word for it.

Here's pretty good source on FFT implementations in python:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/jakevdp.github.io/downloads/notebooks/UnderstandingTheFFT.ipynb
It's rather from speed perspective, but in this case we can actually see that sometimes it comes with simplicity too.

Answer (score 11):

As of scipy `0.14` there is a built-in `scipy.linalg.dft`:

Example with 16 point DFT matrix:

```
>>> import scipy.linalg
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = scipy.linalg.dft(16)
```

Validate unitary property, note matrix is unscaled thus `16*np.eye(16)`:

```
>>> np.allclose(np.abs(np.dot( m.conj().T, m )), 16*np.eye(16))
True
```

For 2D DFT matrix, it's just a issue of tensor product, or specially, Kronecker Product in this case, as we are dealing with matrix algebra.

```
>>> m2 = np.kron(m, m) # 256x256 matrix, flattened from (16,16,16,16) tensor
```

Now we can give it a tiled visualization, it's done by rearranging each row into a square block

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> m2tiled = m2.reshape((16,)*4).transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape((256,256))
>>> plt.subplot(121)
>>> plt.imshow(np.real(m2tiled), cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
>>> plt.subplot(122)
>>> plt.imshow(np.imag(m2tiled), cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
>>> plt.show()
```

Result (real and imag part separately):

[image: 2D DFT basis]

As you can see they are 2D DFT basis functions

[Link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.dft.html) to documentation

Answer (score 3):

@Alex| is basically correct, I add here the version I used for 2-d DFT:

```
def DFT_matrix_2d(N):
    i, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))
    A=np.multiply.outer(i.flatten(), i.flatten())
    B=np.multiply.outer(j.flatten(), j.flatten())
    omega = np.exp(-2*np.pi*1J/N)
    W = np.power(omega, A+B)/N
    return W
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be a little late, but there is a better alternative for creating the DFT  matrix, that performs faster, using NumPy's `vander`

also, this implementation does not use loops (explicitly)

```
def dft_matrix(signal):

    N = signal.shape[0]  # num of samples
    w = np.exp((-2 * np.pi * 1j) / N)  # remove the '-' for inverse fourier
    r = np.arange(N)
    w_matrix = np.vander(w ** r, increasing=True)  # faster than meshgrid
    return w_matrix
```

if I'm not mistaken, the main improvement is that this method generates the elements of the power from the (already calculated) previous elements

---

you can read about `vander` in the documentation:
[numpy.vander](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vander.html)

Answer (score 2):

Lambda functions work too:

```
dftmtx = lambda N: np.fft.fft(np.eye(N))
```

You can call it by using dftmtx(N). Example:

```
In [62]: dftmtx(2)
Out[62]: 
array([[ 1.+0.j,  1.+0.j],
       [ 1.+0.j, -1.+0.j]])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to compute the 2D DFT as a single matrix operation, it is necessary to unravel the matrix X on which you wish to compute the DFT into a vector, as each output of the DFT has a sum over every index in the input, and a single square matrix multiplication does not have this ability. Taking care to be sure we are handling the indices correctly, I find the following works:

```
M = 16
N = 16
X = np.random.random((M,N)) + 1j*np.random.random((M,N))
Y = np.fft.fft2(X)
W = np.zeros((M*N,M*N),dtype=np.complex)
​
hold = []
for m in range(M):
    for n in range(N):
        hold.append((m,n))
​
for j in range(M*N):
    for i in range(M*N):
        k,l = hold[j]
        m,n = hold[i]
        W[j,i] = np.exp(-2*np.pi*1j*(m*k/M + n*l/N))

np.allclose(np.dot(W,X.ravel()),Y.ravel())
True
```

If you wish to change the normalization to orthogonal, you can divide by 1/sqrt(MN) or if you wish to have the inverse transformation, just change the sign in the exponent.